# Openshift 3.11 source-to-image (s2i) build using no standard ssh port

Tags: git, ssh, openshift, okd, s2i

I'm trying to use OpenShift s2i builds to build an image, pulling source code from a git repo on a non standard port (port 222).

I thought this would be as simple as specifying the port in the git repo url, however this doesnt seem to work. When I run this, I get the following:

```
Cloning "git@ssh.gitlab.intnerldomain.com:222/myorg/myproject.git" ...
WARNING: timed out waiting for git server, will wait 1m4s
error: ssh: connect to host ssh.gitlab.intnerldomain.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Note that the git url contains `:222` but the error message state it is using port 22.

How can I tell Openshift, and in particular, source-to-image, to use a custom port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a port in an ssh URL in Git, use `ssh://user@host:port/path/to/repo.git` syntax.  The shorthand `user@host:path` syntax does not allow port insertion.  The URL you used is the equivalent of:

```
ssh://git@ssh.gitlab.intnerldomain.com/222/myorg/myproject.git
```